# Probability of 1 event that has 33% chances over 3 times

Tags: probability

Say a woman wants to use in vitro fertilization. Each time she tries there is a 0,33 probability that she will have a child. She tries 3 times. What is the probability that she will have a child?

I thought something like this:

```
P(a) = 1/3
P(!a) = 2/3
```

We have 3 possibilities:

```
a, !a, !a
!a, a, !a
!a, !a, a
```

All three are the same so:

```
3*(1/3 * 2/3 * 2/3) = 44%
```

But apparently this one is correct:

1 minus the probability that it will not happen:

```
1 - 0.66 * 0.66 * 0.66 = 72%
```

Is the second one correct and why is the first one not ok?

Thanks!

**Update**: From the comment and the answer I understand. But when talking about in vitro fertilization we obviously mean that she will stop after the first child. So wouldn't it be interpreted as only one child?

Comment: The issue lies in the question since there is a difference in having exactly one or at least one child

Comment: If you're assuming she stops after one child, then you'd calculate $P(a)+P(!a,a)+P(!a,!a,a)$, which gives the same answer as the subtraction technique.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Thanks! That  I think is the correct one and it gives 70%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we interpret "a child" to mean **at least one** child. So you need to include the cases where she has more than one child, like $a,a,a$.

Usually, if they want you to calculate the chance of "one child", it's often stated as "exactly one" child.

---

EDIT: It's not obvious that she stops after she succeeds the first time. Perhaps in real life, that's how it works, but this is a word problem. It tells you that she tries 3 times. So I would interpret this as trying all three times regardless of the number of successes.

If they wanted  you to stop after the first success, they would have worded it as something like "she tries until she is successful the first time, up to three tries", in my opinion.